# problems importing python module

Tags: python, module, import

I'm trying to use python's `bitstring` module in a script and am getting an import error.  This error does not happen when running from interactive mode.

Here's the code:

```
import bitstring
b = bitstring.BitArray(bin='001001111')
```

When run like this:

```
python test.py
```

I get this:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'BitArray'
```

However, when I do this:

```
$ python
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:57:41) 
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import bitstring
>>> b = bitstring.BitArray(bin='001001111')
>>> print b
0b001001111
```

It works just fine! It's the same interpreter being run by the same user. Any pointers?

Comment: Print out `bitsrting.__file__` from within the script in non-interactive mode and make sure that it's pointing to the correct file

Comment: Is this happening in the same directory?

Comment: I predict you have created a bitstring.py in your current directory.

Comment: I `pip`ed `bitstring`, ran your code, and I have no issue. I used cpython 2.7 on WinXP. Have you tried running it or installed the `bitstring` properly?

Comment: Michael, you are right!  lol  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Compare your `sys.path` results in the two environments.

Comment: i doubt this is still relivent to the origanal poster but i hope it helps someone trying to find the answer to a problem, my guess would be module caching by the interpreter, if you changed the module and did not reload the interpreter then the module may have been cached

Answer (score 7):

I predict you have created a bitstring.py in your current directory.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by a `bitstring.py` file in `sys.path` of `test.py`, but not in that of the interactive python shell. Most likely, there's a `bitstring.py` file in the directory `test.py` is in, and you started your shell from another working directory.

Since python traverses `sys.path` from front to end, modules in the current directory - even if accidentally created - overshadow those in system library directories.

Answer (score 0):

Google App Engine actually had a [similar issue](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3566) at one point. The easiest solution there was simply comment the offending line or use try...except. Obviously that won't work here.

In that case, the problem was initialization order. A half second later a similar line of code was called again with success. Their solution? refactor. :-(

The best I've seen is a dynamic lookup of the class: `bitstring.__dict__.get("BitArray")` or `getattr(bitstring, "BitArray");`. It isn't ideal (and I believe I've even seen those return null), but hopefully it can get you somewhere.