# AttributeError in Python

Tags: python, python-import

My whole code is

```
import warc

f = warc.open("file.warc.gz")
for record in f:
    print record['WARC-Target-URI'], record['Content-Length']
```

But it gives me this error:

```
  File "warc.py", line 1, in <module>
  import warc
  File "/path/warc.py", line 3, in <module>
  f = warc.open("file.warc.gz")
  AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'open'
```

I just installed warc with `sudo pip install warc`, following these [instructions](http://warc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). The code too is just a copy and paste from that page. 
I don't understand why the import doesn't work. I tried to upgrade the installation too, but it's already up to date.

Comment: try to check the import [using imp](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14050282/4353946).

Comment: thanks! it says True, though. It finds it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally discovered the problem [reading this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6231853/problems-importing-python-module). I had called my script `warc.py`, and that generated the conflict. Careful how you name your files.